# UI not updating even though updates are called from main thread

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsthread, performselector

I've read all related questions I could find but I'm still stuck, so I hope someone will spot my reasoning error.

I'm trying to periodically update some UIView. For simplicity, I've reduced the code to what's below. Summary: In viewDidLoad, I call a method on a new background thread. That method calls a method on the main thread which is supposed to update some UILabel. The code seems to work correctly: the background thread is not the main thread and the method calling the UILabel update is on the main thread. In code:

In viewDidLoad:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(updateMeters) withObject:self];
```

This creates a new background thread. My method updateMeters (for simplicity) now looks like this:

```
if ([NSThread isMainThread]) { //this evaluates to FALSE, as it's supposed to
    NSLog(@"Running on main, that's wrong!");
}
while (i < 10) {
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateUI) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
//The code below yields the same result
//        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
//            [self updateUI];
//        });
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval: 1.05];
    ++i;
}
```

Finally, updateUI does just that:

```
if ([NSThread isMainThread]) { //Evaluates to TRUE; it's indeed on the main thread!
    NSLog(@"main thread!");
} else {
    NSLog(@"not main thread!");
}
NSLog(@"%f", someTimeDependentValue); //logs the value I want to update to the screen
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", someTimeDependentValue]; //does not update
```

For all I know, this should work. But it doesn't, unfortunately... The commented out `dispatch_async()` yields the same result.

Comment: What is "someTimeDependentValue"? A float I suppose..

Comment: Have you tried using a NSTimer?  Perhaps in viewDidLoad, you kick off a NSTimer.  On tick, have it perform your UI update.  Using 2 seperate,self-referencing processes in a single view is a bit confusing.

Comment: @Jeremy Do you mean something like this?
    `[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(updateMeters) withObject:self];`

    `NSInvocation *invoc = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:[self methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(updateUI)]];`

    `[NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1. invocation:invoc repeats:YES];`

I'm unfamiliar with NSInvocation objects, so I'm not sure this is correct. With this code, updateUI does not get called.

Comment: I'm not getting what it should update, which is the value. Have you ever considered that may someTimeDependentValue is not valorized?. check with an NSlog or breakpoint if it does have some value inside.

Comment: @Andrea I'm sorry. For the sake of compactness, I removed an NSLog() statement. someTimeDependentValue does get updated.

Comment: Hi Tom try to force an update on the label calling -setNeedsDisplay on the main view or just on the label(for performance reason just the label should be better).

Comment: @Andrea Unfortunately, that's not working.

Comment: Let's try to do step by step... I will ask stupid question :-). If you do not spawn the -updateMeters on a background thread is everything working? Are you really sure that if you put a NSLog before the line label.text someTimeDependentValue is valorized? Are you sure that the someTimeDep... is float ? If your label is an outlet are you sure that you made the right connection?

Comment: @Andrea thanks for the suggestions :)
- If I run everything on the main thread, the screen never gets updated, probably because the main thread hangs in the while loop in `-updateMeters`
- Yes, my float has a value
- Yes, my outlets are connected. I changed the label text programmatically in `-viewDidLoad` to double check

Comment: I agree with Brian saying that is not threading related, probably is something else. Try to NSLog(@"UpdateValue %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", someTimeDependentValue]); right before or after using the label property. Probably the string generated is NULL

Comment: @Andrea Actually, the string generated is this: `UpdateValue -63.211559` (and it changes every second). Nice double check, though :)

Comment: If someTimeDependentValue is updated to the correct value in the updateUI method, which you have established to be called on the main thread, that suggests to me that there is something wrong with the label reference at that point, like maybe it is nil at that point.

Comment: As Brian said try to put another NSLog asking for the description of the label such as NSLog(@"The label is %@",label); it should print  out different stuff if the label exists.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Andrea. See my last comment in the answer to see what was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you have your format statement wrong.

```
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", someTimeDependentValue];
```

Make sure that someTimeDependentValue is a float. If it is an int it will likely get formatted to 0.0000.

[Here's a repo](https://github.com/blcooley/TestForSO) showing a working version of what you describe. Whatever is wrong is not related to the threading.

Comment: In other words, you're saying that my code as I listed it in my question should work?

Comment: It is working in that repo. I pretty much just copied and pasted your code into a subclass of UIViewController. The only snag I hit was that I originally declared tdv (an instance variable I created to replace someTimeDependentValue) as an int because I did not notice that your stringWithFormat was asking for a float/double.

Comment: That's weird. I have an `NSLog()` in the method as well and that's printing the (updating) value. So one thing I'm pretty sure of, is that the format statement is correct and the value I provide is correct as well. I'll update my question to reflect that.

Comment: Many thanks for the repo! I should be able to find my error using this!

Comment: Well, there's definitely something wrong with the outlet... When I change the reference from weak to strong, I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS returned in my methods, except for directly in ViewDidLoad. I tried to isolate the problem by creating the label programmatically, but that yields the same error. I'm really puzzled (and very afraid that I'm missing something really obvious)...

Comment: Sir, you have been very right in that the code should work. Actually, everything in my code seems to be perfectly fine. I've now isolated one single line of code (calling audioQueueGetProperty()) that apparently causes all my outlets to be overwritten in memory. I'm still quite clueless on what's going wrong there, but as far this question goes, you've been correct in analyzing the problem. Thanks for that :)

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comment, here's a scenario that might be best achieved using a NSTimer:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
       NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:<number of seconds per tick> target:self selector:@selector(timerTick:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)timerTick:(id)sender
{
      label.text = ...;
}
```

There is a more elaborate approach which I use extensively in my projects.  And that is the concept of an engine.

I would have an engine that runs in the background using a timer.  And at key moments, it would post a notification using `NSNotificationCenter` on the main thread using `dispatch_async`/`dispatch_get_main_thread()` and any one of your views can then subscribe and handle that notification by updating their UI.